# Может ли экземпляр структуры храниться в куче (heap)?

Tags: c#

Как это сделать? Объясните пожалуйста простыми словами

Comment: Может. Это называется [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

Comment: Например, есть класс с полем типа `int`. Содержимое экземпляра этого класса будет хранится в куче, вместе с `int`, который является экземпляром структуры.

Comment: Может быть элементом массива например, а массив - ссылочный тип. На самом деле вопрос можно переформулировать как "могут ли все без исключения данные храниться не в стеке?". Да, могут. Стек вообще не для данных придумали, а для переходв и возврата из методов, он даже называется "Стек вызовов" (Call Stack). Это просто хитрые программисты придумали как по-быстрому через стек проводить вычисления в локальной области видимости.